# Need help in Java Socket Programming[server & client]

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have created a Java server named `server.java` using java sockets which accepts a string from a client (`client.java`) on Android, modifies it and send the modified string to the client [which in my case is an Android app].

When I tried to run both of them, without any error the android app successfully sends the user inputted string to the server. The problem arises when server receives the string, sometimes the server does not provide any output. But if the client is closed (or killed) then server terminal outputs as :

```
 message received from client is: null
 request: Message sent to the client : i received message:null
 message received from client is: null
 request: Message sent to the client : i received message:null
 message received from client is: null
 request: Message sent to the client : i received message:null
 message received from client is: null
 request: Message sent to the client : i received message:null
 message received from client is: null
 request: Message sent to the client : i received message:null
```

Here is the code for `Server.java` which runs in a desktop computer:

```
public class Server {
    static Socket socket;
    static PrintWriter out;
    static BufferedReader  in;
    static int port = 9999;

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        String query="blank", returnMessage="Server malfunctioning!";

        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Server Started and listening to the port "+port);
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

            while(true) {
                try {
                    query=in.readLine();
                    System.out.println("message received from client is: "+query);
                    //Processing the query.
                    returnMessage="i received message:"+query;

                    //Sending the response back to the client.
                    out.print(returnMessage);
                    System.out.println("request: Message sent to the client : " + returnMessage);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is `ServerConnect.java` which extends `AsyncTask`:

```
public class ServerConnect extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Void> {
    String TAG="Server";  
    String message="empty response";
    String ip="EMPTY QUERY";
    WebView wb;
    TextToSpeech tts;
    String host = "192.168.2.3";
    int port = 9999;
    PrintWriter out;
    BufferedReader  in;
    Socket  socket;

    ServerConnect(String inp, WebView wbb, TextToSpeech ts) {
       ip=inp;
       this.wb=wbb;
       tts=ts;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Object... voids) {
        Log.d(TAG, "ip value "+ip);
        try {
            // InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            socket = new Socket(host, port);
            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            try {
                //Send the message to the server
                out.print(ip);
                //out.flush();
                Log.d(TAG, "request: Message sent to the server : " + ip);
                message = in.readLine();
                Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: message" + message);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                message = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                message = "My Brain is not working! Reason is: "+e;
            } finally {
                in.close();
                out.flush();
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: finally block");

            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        if(message!=null) {
            wb.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, message, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
            tts.speak(stripHtml(message), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
            if (!(pullLinks(stripHtml(message)).equals(""))) {
                wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                wb.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {});
                wb.loadUrl(pullLinks(message));
                //ip.setText("");
                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }
        } else {
            wb.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "Message is null!", "text/html", "utf-8", null);
            tts.speak("Message is null!", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
        }
    }

    public String stripHtml(String html) {
        return Html.fromHtml(html).toString(); 
    }

    private String pullLinks(String text) {
        String links="";

        String regex = "\\(?\\b(http://|www[.])[-A-Za-z0-9+&amp;@#/%?=~_()|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9+&amp;@#/%=~_()|]";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);

        while(m.find()) {
            String urlStr = m.group();
            if (urlStr.startsWith("(") && urlStr.endsWith(")"))
                urlStr = urlStr.substring(1, urlStr.length() - 1);

            links=urlStr;
        }

        return links;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I suggest your existing technology for creating client-server communications?

Comment: try to flush the writer at the end at server side

Comment: Create a thread to process the input & output. The first connected client is blocking all other clients.

Comment: The server reads a line from the client. So the client did sent a line. After that the server sends the sltered message back. But not as line. Your server should send lines too and youf client should try to read lines.

Comment: Further: if the server cannot read a line. So when readLine returns null, then why send a response message to the client? The server should only reply to the client if it indeed received something from the client.

Answer (score 0):

`readLine()` returns null at end of stream, i.e. when the peer has closed the connection. You aren't detecting that case: you are treating the null as data. You need to terminate the read loop when you get the null.

NB `UnknownHostException` cannot be thrown by either `print()` or `readLine()`.